# Error 'cannot bind 'std::ostream' al implementar una plantilla en C++

Tags: c++, template

AL modificar un `TAD` con `templates` para hacerlo genérico(añadir templates):

Para entrada/salida de datos tengo este código:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Matriz & m)
{
  os << m.filas() << " " << m.columnas() << std::endl;
  os << std::setprecision(4) << std::fixed;
  for(int i=1; i <= m.filas(); i++)
  {
    for(int j=1; j <= m.columnas(); j++)
    {
      os << m.valor(i,j) << " ";
    }
    os << std::endl;
  }

  return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matriz& m)
{
  int filas, columnas;
  float v;

  is >> filas >> columnas;
  for (int i=1; i<=filas; i++)
  {
    for (int j=1; j<=columnas; j++)
    {
      is >> v;
      m.asignar(i,j,v);
    }
  }

  return is;
}
```

La definición(resumido):

```
#ifndef MATRIZ_HPP
#define MATRIZ_HPP

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename E, int F, int C>
class Matriz
{
public:
  Matriz();
private:
  E elementos_[F][C];
};
#include "matriz.cpp"
#include "matriz_io.cpp"

#endif // MATRIZ_HPP
```

La implementación(resumido):

```
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

template<typename E, int F, int C>
Matriz<E,F,C>::Matriz()
{
  for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
    {
      elementos_[i][j] = 0; // Valor int, C++ lo convierte automáticamente a E.
    }
  }
}
```

Aquí salta error:

```
#include "matriz.hpp"

#define Elemento float

#define MatrizPrueba Matriz<Elemento, 3, 3>

void probarCrearMatriz()
{
  MatrizPrueba m;
  std::cout << m;
}
```

**Este error:**

> error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}'
>   lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'    std::cout << m;

¿Alguna idea de porque se produce?

PD: si quito la `template` el código va perfecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno aquí dejo el código que conseguí solucionar, tengo [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80798/problemas-al-implementar-la-plantilla-al-tad) donde muestro todos los archivos por si alguien quiere verlos.

Aquí va la solución al código, hay que poner `templates` también en el overloading de `matriz_io.cpp`

```
 template<typename E, int filas, int columnas>
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Matriz<E,filas,columnas>& m)
 {
   os << m.filas() << " " << m.columnas() << std::endl;
   os << std::setprecision(4) << std::fixed;
   for(int i=1; i <= m.filas(); i++)
   {
     for(int j=1; j <= m.columnas(); j++)
     {
       os << m.valor(i,j) << " ";
     }
     os << std::endl;
   }

   return os;
 }
 template<typename E, int F, int C>
 std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matriz<E,F,C>& m)
 {
     int filas, columnas;

   E v;

   is >> filas >> columnas;
   for (int i=1; i<=filas; i++)
   {
     for (int j=1; j<=columnas; j++)
     {
       is >> v;
       m.asignar(i,j,v);
     }
   }

   return is;
 }
```

Comment: Si esta solución responde tu pregunta, por favor, márcala como "solución"

Comment: Hasta dentro de 7 horas no puedo.